# Can't add an image background to div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a background image to a div, but it is not working, can you please help me!

```css
html body {
  height: 100%;
}

.front-page {
  display: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: url("classroom.jpg") no-repeat center cover;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="front-page">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: `display: 100%;` isn't valid. And without content or a height your background won't be seen (assuming that the path to the image is correct)

Comment: After removing the display:100%; also look into changing the background property.    To cover the entire background try:  background: url("classroom.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Three Issues:**

1. Your `div` has no height/padding, meaning it renders with a height of 0px. This means your `div` is not visible, and thus, the background doesn't show.
2. `display: 100%;` is not valid - not sure what this was meant to accomplish.
3. The `background` shorthand syntax requires a `/` between size and position.

```css
.front-page {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  background: url("http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/200/287.jpg") no-repeat center/cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="front-page">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put the `position` and `size` on a seperate line and at some height to it, it works :) (and ofcourse delete the `display: 100%`)

@avril is correct if you prefer it on a single line.

```css
.front-page {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/sS2JdeMNoRc/0.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="front-page">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I did it differently. Look again at my answer :)

Answer (score -1):

**CSS Syntax**

> background: bg-color bg-image position/bg-size bg-repeat bg-origin bg-clip bg-attachment initial|inherit;

*The `cover` property is the problem* and `display: 100%;` isn't valid.

try

```
.front-page {
  ...
  height: 100%;
  background: url(classroom.jpg) center/cover no-repeat;
  ...
}
```

or

```
.front-page {
  ...
  height: 100%;
  background: url("classroom.jpg") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  ...
}
```

Comment: While the background shorthand is an issue in this case, there are others as well. If you modify OP's example to simply adopt this change, the background will still not show.

Comment: @Santi yes. Look again... Is not giving error in the CSS of the console

Comment: Just because the error is no longer in console doesn't mean that it works... did you test it? The background is still not visible. https://jsfiddle.net/6vb2jhoz/ - Your answer is missing a key element that is necessary in solving the issue. See mine or Ivaro's answers.

Comment: Also, I noticed you now added `height: 100%;`, which still won't work because you cannot use percentage-based heights unless an ancestor has a specified unit height. https://jsfiddle.net/6vb2jhoz/1/ - Again, I highly suggest simply testing your answers before posting them!